# Change colour of progress bar depending on value: Jquery Mobile

Tags: jquery, css, jquery-mobile, progress-bar, checkboxlist

I currently have a progress bar which is green. I want the progress bar to change depending on the value, ideally begin red, then gradually change to yellow, then when the bar is nearly full show green. Demo=http://jsfiddle.net/R24pf/

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
    <title>Bars for checklist</title>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1" />

    <meta charset="utf-8">



    <link rel="stylesheet" href="jqm/demos/css/themes/default/jquery.mobile-1.3.2.min.css" />


    <script src="jqm/demos/js/jquery.js">
    </script>

    <script src="jqm/demos/js/jquery.mobile-1.3.2.min.js">
    </script>

    <script>
        $(document).on('pagebeforeshow', '#checklist', function () {
            $('input[type="checkbox"]').each(function () {
                ($(this).is(':checked')) ? $(this).parent().parent().addClass('checked') : $(this).parent().parent().addClass('not-checked');
            });
        });


        $(document).on('click', '.checkBoxLeft', function () {
            if ($(this).find('input[type="checkbox"]').is(':checked')) {
                $(this).removeClass('checked').addClass('not-checked');
                $(this).find('input[type="checkbox"]').attr('checked', false);
            } else {
                $(this).removeClass('not-checked').addClass('checked');
                $(this).find('input[type="checkbox"]').attr('checked', true);
            }





            var total = $("#theList input[type=checkbox]").length;
            var numChecked = $("#theList input[type=checkbox]:checked").length;
            var prog = numChecked * 100 / total;
            $("#progress").css("width", prog + "%");

        });
    </script>
</head>

<body>




    <div data-role="main" class="ui-content">
        <div data-role="collapsible">
            <h1>Checklist with progress made</h1>



            <div data-role="content">
                <ul data-role="listview" id="theList" data-inset="true">
                    <li>



                        <div class="checkBoxLeft">
                            <input type="checkbox" name="checkbox-0" id="checkbox-0" class="hidden-checkbox" />
                        </div>
                        <a href="" class="detailListText">1</a>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                        <div class="checkBoxLeft">
                            <input type="checkbox" name="checkbox-0" id="checkbox-0" class="hidden-checkbox" />
                        </div>
                        <a href="" class="detailListText">2</a>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                        <div class="checkBoxLeft">
                            <input type="checkbox" name="checkbox-0" id="checkbox-0" class="hidden-checkbox" />
                        </div>
                        <a href="" class="detailListText">3</a>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                        <div class="checkBoxLeft">
                            <input type="checkbox" name="checkbox-0" id="checkbox-0" class="hidden-checkbox" />
                        </div>
                        <a href="" class="detailListText">4</a>
                    </li>

                </ul>
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="meter green nostripes">
            <span id="progress" style="width: 0%"></span>
        </div>
    </div>






    <style>
        .detailListText {
            margin: 0 0 0 20px;
        }
        .checkBoxLeft {
            position: absolute;
            left: 10px;
            top: 28%;
            width: 18px;
            height: 18px;
            background: #d9d9d9;
            border-radius: 3px;
        }
        .hidden-checkbox {
            display: none;
        }
        .not-checked {
            background-position: 18px 0;
            background-color: #d9d9d9;
        }
        .checked {
            background-position: 0 0;
            background-color: #6496bc;
        }
        .meter {
            height: 20px;
            position: relative;
            margin: 60px 0 20px 0;
            background: #555;
            -moz-border-radius: 25px;
            -webkit-border-radius: 25px;
            border-radius: 25px;
            padding: 10px;
            -webkit-box-shadow: inset 0 -1px 1px rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.3);
            -moz-box-shadow: inset 0 -1px 1px rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.3);
            box-shadow: inset 0 -1px 1px rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.3);
        }
        .meter > span {
            display: block;
            height: 100%;
            -webkit-border-top-right-radius: 8px;
            -webkit-border-bottom-right-radius: 8px;
            -moz-border-radius-topright: 8px;
            -moz-border-radius-bottomright: 8px;
            border-top-right-radius: 8px;
            border-bottom-right-radius: 8px;
            -webkit-border-top-left-radius: 20px;
            -webkit-border-bottom-left-radius: 20px;
            -moz-border-radius-topleft: 20px;
            -moz-border-radius-bottomleft: 20px;
            border-top-left-radius: 20px;
            border-bottom-left-radius: 20px;
            background-color: rgb(43, 194, 83);
            background-image: -webkit-gradient(linear, left bottom, left top, color-stop(0, rgb(43, 194, 83)), color-stop(1, rgb(84, 240, 84)));
            background-image: -moz-linear-gradient(center bottom, rgb(43, 194, 83) 37%, rgb(84, 240, 84) 69%);
            -webkit-box-shadow: inset 0 2px 9px rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.3), inset 0 -2px 6px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.4);
            -moz-box-shadow: inset 0 2px 9px rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.3), inset 0 -2px 6px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.4);
            box-shadow: inset 0 2px 9px rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.3), inset 0 -2px 6px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.4);
            position: relative;
            overflow: hidden;
        }
        .meter > span:after,
        .animate > span > span {
            content: "";
            position: absolute;
            top: 0;
            left: 0;
            bottom: 0;
            right: 0;
            background-image: -webkit-gradient(linear, 0 0, 100% 100%, color-stop(.25, rgba(255, 255, 255, .2)), color-stop(.25, transparent), color-stop(.5, transparent), color-stop(.5, rgba(255, 255, 255, .2)), color-stop(.75, rgba(255, 255, 255, .2)), color-stop(.75, transparent), to(transparent));
            background-image: -moz-linear-gradient(-45deg, rgba(255, 255, 255, .2) 25%, transparent 25%, transparent 50%, rgba(255, 255, 255, .2) 50%, rgba(255, 255, 255, .2) 75%, transparent 75%, transparent);
            z-index: 1;
            -webkit-background-size: 50px 50px;
            -moz-background-size: 50px 50px;
            background-size: 50px 50px;
            -webkit-animation: move 2s linear infinite;
            -moz-animation: move 2s linear infinite;
            -webkit-border-top-right-radius: 8px;
            -webkit-border-bottom-right-radius: 8px;
            -moz-border-radius-topright: 8px;
            -moz-border-radius-bottomright: 8px;
            border-top-right-radius: 8px;
            border-bottom-right-radius: 8px;
            -webkit-border-top-left-radius: 20px;
            -webkit-border-bottom-left-radius: 20px;
            -moz-border-radius-topleft: 20px;
            -moz-border-radius-bottomleft: 20px;
            border-top-left-radius: 20px;
            border-bottom-left-radius: 20px;
            overflow: hidden;
        }
        .animate > span:after {
            display: none;
        }
    </style>
    </div>
</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This can be accomplished by adding a simple if else statement under the "numChecked" variable, of course this could also be done using an array, or even a switch statement, but this code should get you on your way so you can improve upon it in the future.

**Example:** http://jsfiddle.net/7W72B/

```
        if(numChecked == 1){
            $("#progress").css('background','red');
        } else if(numChecked == 2){
            $("#progress").css('background','orange');
        } else if(numChecked == 3){
            $("#progress").css('background','yellow');
        } else {
            $("#progress").css('background','lime');
        }
```

I hope this gets you started, good luck.